# Automatically set env variables in Heroku review app using pipelines

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, environment-variables

I am using Heroku pipelines. So when I push to github master branch. Code is automatically deploys to staging app. Inside that staging app on Heroku I have environment variables. The problem is when I make a pull request, Heroku automatically makes review app. This review app doesn't have my env variables. How do I make it so Heroku automatically adds my ENV variables when it creates review branch?

Answer (score 2):

On the new version of Review Apps in Heroku you need to specify the ENV variables in the Pipeline: under Settings -> Config Vars  - the old version (late 2019 sometime) could inherit them, but in the new "Improved?" version you have to specify them.  There is no copy method either, so you have to do each one manually unfortunately.

[image: example showing where the Setting button is for Heroku Piplines in 2020]

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your config vars to your review app config vars using the method defined on this page. The documentation states that there should be at least one review app. In my case, I didn't have any review apps but was still able to copy them to my review config.
BTW: I grabbed my review id out of the URL: (looks like) dc0d55c4-52ag-4aac-2ba9-37d925c00285

https://help.heroku.com/RVEKYMZQ/how-to-copy-staging-dev-production-application-config-variable-to-review-app-config-vars

```
https://api.heroku.com/pipelines/{pipeline_id}/stage/review/config-vars -d "$CONFIG_VARS" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

Comment: The link is cool but it seems wrong: @canuckT's solution works.